# Save Array in rails 4

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to keep my array in mysql with rails 4.

controller.rb

```
def emission_params
  params.require(:emission).permit(:name,:key,:phone,:address,:country,:state,:city,:email,:template,:content,:news_source)
end
```

In my def create

```
  def create
@emission = Emission.new(emission_params)
  end
```

The problem is that if I add the following does not keep the array in the database.

```
def create
  @emission = Emission.new(emission_params)
  @emission.news_source = params[:news_source]
end
```

Because you can not save only the first example unused `@emission.news_source = params [: NEWS_SOURCE] ??`

Comment: please post your parameters that are coming through to your create request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this to work in a development environment...

```
params.require(:emission).permit(:name, :key, :phone, :address, :country, :state, :city, :email, :template, :content, {news_source: []})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def emission_params
  params.require(:emission).permit(:name, :key, :phone, :address, :country, :state, :city, :email, :template, :content, news_source: [])
end
```

use "[]" after array attribute.

Comment: SyntaxError in EmissionsController#new
 syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting => ...art, news_source: [],:football,:color,:path_sponsor,:id_team... ... ^

Comment: Try putting news_source as the last param.

Comment: Josh Hunter Save "NULL"

Comment: from the UI, u need to pass it as an array. Other wise it will save as empty.